# At what point does a tax become a ban?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, tax-law, us-constitution

I believe that it is mostly uncontroversial that it is constitutional for a state to tax firearm purchases at a reasonable rate. If a state had a law imposing a 10% sales tax on all firearm and ammunition purchases, this might be politically controversial, but I believe that most people would accept that the law is constitutional.

What if the tax rate is set to 50%? 100%? 1000%? Above a certain point, I would expect that an extremely high tax would be seen as equivalent to a ban. It would be a major loophole in the Second Amendment if the government could say "sure, you can buy that gun for $1,000, but only after you pay $1,000,000 in taxes." At what point are sales taxes on constitutionally protected sales unconstitutional?

(I'm using firearms as an example, but the question applies equally to any case in which something can be taxed but not banned.)

Answer (score 1):

States have the power to impose fines for engaging in prohibited behavior, which fines may not be excessive under the 8th Amendment. Possession of firearms is not outlawed and therefore cannot subject to a fine. In the case of a criminal penalty, we can determine that a $114,948 fine for illegally smuggling $114,948 is not excessive, see [US v. Jose](https://casetext.com/case/us-v-jose-2), 499 F.3d 105. That is, there is no specific dollar amount that is deemed to be legally "excessive".

Since we are dealing with an enumerated constitutional right, the restriction (tax) is subject to strict scrutiny. There is no "legitimate government interest" in prohibiting sale of firearms, instead the justification must be something else (let's say "firearms safety education"). An excise tax can be imposed, just as there are additional taxes on alcohol, tobacco and marijuana. Tobacco taxes are on a unit basis, but can approach 100%. See [New York State Assn. of Tobacco & Candy Distribs., Inc. v City of New York](https://law.justia.com/cases/new-york/other-courts/2003/2003-23982.html) for a challenge (which failed). The problem, as stated in [Magnano Co. v Hamilton](https://casetext.com/case/magnano-co-v-hamilton#p45), 292 US 40, is that

> Collateral purposes or motives of a legislature in levying a tax of a
> kind within the reach of its lawful power are matters beyond the scope
> of judicial inquiry. Nor may a tax within the lawful power of a state
> be judicially stricken down under the due process clause simply
> because its enforcement may or will result, in restricting or even
> destroying particular occupations or business

The argument about the tax would therefore have to reduce to a clear unconstitutional restriction on the individual's Second Amendment rights, and not the amount per se.

Comment: "There is no "legitimate government interest" in prohibiting sale of firearms,"  what?

Comment: @TigerGuy is there a legitimate government interest in prohibiting political speech? A legitimate government interest in conducting unreasonable searches? In mandating a religion? There can't be a legitimate government interest in prohibiting something to which the Constitution guarantees a right.

Comment: Rights are abridged all the time, and political speech has been prohibited in the past. You can't buy new machine guns despite "shall not be abridged."

Comment: @TigerGuy there may be a legitimate interest in banning certain types of guns, but not in banning all guns or all gun sales.

Comment: Do you have any authority for the proposition that such a tax would be subject to strict scrutiny? Infringements of many constitutional rights are analyzed under much more forgiving standards.

Comment: "there is no specific dollar amount that is deemed to be legally "excessive"": while there may not be a specific threshold where a fine becomes excessive, there are certainly fines that would unambiguously be excessive.  For example, a fine of half a billion dollars for a first-time offense of failing to declare the import or export of $11,000 would be excessive.

Comment: @TigerGuy:  In those cases, U.S. courts have held that the restriction must be the least intrusive method to achieve the legitimate and compelling government interest.   It should also be noted that almost all restrictions on speech are content neutral restrictions and there is no words or ideas that are out right banned.

Comment: The was a fairly recent case maybe out of Hawaii or Guam or American Samoa where a gun tax was held to be unconstitutional due to the Second Amendment.

Comment: Wow. An "Association of Tobacco and Candy Distributors" is not at all a problematic thing to have exist. /s

Comment: @ohwilleke It probably wouldn't be American Samoa, since the Constitution isn't presumed to apply there unless something has changed quite recently. (DC, PR, USVI, CNMI, Guam, and the uninhabited Midway Island all have special laws that say that the Constitution _does_ apply in those places, but AS does not.)

Comment: @A.R. American Samoans don't benefit from birthright citizenship under the 14th Amendment, but that doesn't mean that the constitution doesn't apply there. The case I was reaching for, however, was *Murphy v. Guerrero* https://casetext.com/case/murphy-v-guerrero arising in the Northern Mariana Islands.

Comment: @ohwilleke Under _Downes v. Bidwell_, the entire Constitution does not apply to the governance of American Samoa and other "unincorporated" territories, except possibly for provisions related to "the liberty and property of the citizen." There is no precedent for whether all or any provisions of the 2nd Amendment fall under that exception.

Comment: @A..R. No time to consider or respond at the moment but the link to the 1901 case for anyone interested is https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/182/244/